# exposing orientdb studio behind a reverse-proxy/load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, orientdb3.0

What is the right approach to exposing the orientdb studio behind a reverse proxy?  i have multiple endpoints running behind a load balancer reverse-proxy and i mapped /studio to the orientdb port but looks like it is making rest calls at root context.  for e.g. as soon as the page loads, it makes a call to listDatabases and fails there.  i could easily add listDatabases to the reverse proxy configuration but im sure that listDatabases is the first of many XHR calls the studio will make.

Wanted to know what it the easiest or recommended way of setting this up

EDIT: On further research I found that using nginx or apache in between is one way of doing this.  I already use a gcp https proxy and URL maps.  Would like to avoid one more level of indirection of at all possible.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming that i was able to accomplish this using a combination of nginx rewrite/reverse proxy and NEG backend services